# Display query string values in django templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, query-string

I wanted to print some success messages from get method back to the index page(home.html) i.e template page with the help of query string. I have redirected to the index page using

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/mysite/q="+successfailure)
```

Now i wanted to print the string success along with other contents in the index file( or template file / home.html file).

I have searched for the solution and found that " django.core.context_processors.request context " should be added to the settings. But i did not find the place to add it. I am currently using python 2.7 and django 1.4.3.

I also tried to use

```
render_to_response("home.html",{'q':successfailure})
```

However, the result is printed in the current page(addContent.html- which I dont want) but i want to send the url into '/mysite/' and print the result there.

Please suggest the appropriate solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

these are the default context processors:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext

```
TEMPLATES = [ {"OPTIONS": { "context_processors": [
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
]}}]
```

if its not in your settings than you haven't overridden it yet. do that now.

then in your template, something like this:

```
{% if request.GET.q %}<div>{{ request.GET.q }}</div>{% endif %}
```

also, I'm noticing in your link url you are not using a querystring operator, `?`. You should be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/mysite/?q="+successfailure)
```

Comment: "django.core.context_processors.request"  is now "django.template.context_processors.request"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can access the querystring in your view with `request.GET`.

So you could adjust the view that renders home.html by adding the successfailure variable into the context. Something like -

```
def home_view(request):
    #....
    successfailure = request.GET
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'succsessfailure': successfailure.iteritems()})
```

Then iterate throught the variables in your template

```
{% for key, value in successfailure %}
    <p>{{ key }} {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If there's a specific key in the querystring you can get the value with `request.GET['your_key']` and drop the call to `iteritems()` (along with the iteration in the template).

Comment: @user2081099 you can mark my answer as the accepted answer by clicking the big grey tick in the top left of my answer (personally I prefer Francis' solution)

Comment: Top suggestion @AidanEwen, I needed to trigger a bootstrap modal window on form.is_valid() failure and this technique worked a treat..

Answer (score 0):

To **Django Templates**, you better redirect with **session** using **request.session["key"]** as shown below because it's easier:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request): 
            # Here
    request.session["messages"] = {"success": "Success", "fail": "Fail"}
    return redirect('/mysite')
```

```
# "home.html"

{{ request.session.messages.success }} {# Success #}
{{ request.session.messages.fail }}    {# Fail #}
```

In addition, to **Django Templates**, you can also redirect with **the several types of messages** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.contrib import messages # Here
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request): 
    messages.debug(request, 'This is debug')
    messages.info(request, 'This is info')
    messages.success(request, 'This is success')
    messages.warning(request, 'This is warning')
    messages.error(request, 'This is error')
    return redirect("/mysite")
```

```
# "home.html"

{% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">

</head>
{% load i18n %}

<body class="{% if is_popup %}popup {% endif %}{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}"
  data-admin-utc-offset="{% now "Z" %}">

{% if messages %}
<ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
{% endfor %}</ul>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

But, I don't know why only **"debug" message** is not displayed even though **"DEBUG = True"** in **"settings.py"**:

[image]

Comment: The [MESSAGE_LEVEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#message-level) setting controls the minimum message level that is recorded. The default for this is INFO which is why DEBUG messages aren't recorded.